# umask for new subdirectories

Tags: umask, transmission

I am running transmission-remote and want all new torrent downloads to be created with g+w permissions.

The transmission Downloads directory is symlinked to a `Downloads` directory on a second drive

as user stephen ( a member of the transmission group )  I can run

```
 [stephen@flip:/mnt/sdb/Downloads]
 :> umask g+w .

 [stephen@flip:/mnt/sdb/Downloads]
 :> umask -S
 u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx
```

which seems to be successful, however transmission is creating new directories with `drwxr-xr-x`

I suppose I should run the umask command as transmission, but that is a `nologin` user probably for good reason so I'll try sudo ...

```
:> sudo -u transmission umask g+w .
sudo: umask: command not found
```

okay so I'll call umask through its path but :

```
[stephen@flip:/mnt/sdb/Downloads]
:> which umask
which: no umask in <PATH>

[stephen@flip:/mnt/sdb/Downloads]
:> alias umask
bash: alias: umask: not found
```

What can/should I do?

Comment: What is your `umask` setting in your `settings.json` file?

Comment: the file creation mask is inherited from parent process to child process, it's not per-user (the same as environment variables and group memberships etc.). So you can't usefully change it from an external program, like an `umask` command that would be in `PATH`. You either need to change the umask of the server process, or use default ACLs

Comment: @JimL. Ah. `"umask": 18,`

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks! That explains a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/157471/), you need to change your `settings.json` file.

Where you have:

```
umask 18
```

you need:

```
umask 2
```

Be certain to restart the transmission daemon after making that change.